# Dojo: How to assign value in Input Field on MouseOver

Tags: dojo

I want "Sample" word in input field on mouseover on raitingDiv

```
dojo.ready(function(){ 
   dojo.query(".raitingDiv").onmouseover(function(e){
        query(".raiting").val('Sample');
  });
});

<input type="text" class="raiting">
<div class="raitingDiv" id="raitingDiv">
  This is sample Text
</div>
```

Following Error occur.
ReferenceError: query is not defined
query(".raiting").val('Sample');

Comment: have you required the `dojo/query` module. `require([
    "dojo/ready", "dojo/query"
], function(ready, query) { ... your code over here ... });`

Answer (score 0):

You need to require the "dojo/query" module for using it in your app.

```
require([
    "dojo/ready", "dojo/query"
], function(ready, query) { 

   ready(function(){ 
     query(".raitingDiv").onmouseover(function(e){
        query(".raiting").val('Sample');
     });
  });

});
```

**EDIT 1:**
dojo/query returns an array of object. so to get the element, we can use the array operator as shown below.

```
require([
    "dojo/ready", "dojo/query"
], function(ready, query) { 

   ready(function(){ 
     query(".raitingDiv").onmouseover(function(e){
        query(".raiting")[0].value = "Sample";
     });
  });

});
```

Comment: Thanks Frank but still i am facing error...

TypeError: query(...).val is not a function
query(".raiting").val('Sample');